# Angularjs: matching password fires too quickly?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to match two text field password whick looks like this:

pwCheck.js

```
angular.module('installApp')
.directive('pwCheck', function ($http) {
  return {
   require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      var firstPassword = '#' + attrs.pwCheck;
        elem.add(firstPassword).on('keyup', function () {
          scope.$apply(function () {
                ctrl.$setValidity('pwmatch', elem.val() === $(firstPassword).val());
            });
        });
      }
   }
});
```

accounts.html

```
<label>{{label.password}}</label>
   <input type="password"  class="form-control" id="pw1" name="pw1"  ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}" ng-model="user.password" required ></input>

<label>{{label.retypePassword}}</label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pw2" name="pw2" ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}" ng-model="pw2" ng-required="" pw-check="pw1"></input>

<div class="msg-block" ng-show="signupform.$error"><img src = "./images/error-icon.png" width = "25" height = "25" ng-show="signupform.pw2.$error.pwmatch"></img><span class="msg-error" ng-show="signupform.pw2.$error.pwmatch">Passwords don't match.</span></div>
```

The above code is working fine as expected but gives a horrible user experience. That happen because when I type in the first textfield the message "Password don't match" will show even the user does not finish typing.

The problem is that the validation happens too quickly, before the user has finished typing.

I have tried to solve this by adding `ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}"` but the problem is still exist.

Help! Thanks in advance

Comment: why dont you change the 'keyup' to 'blur'

Comment: I tried that and thank you it's working now. .

Comment: If using angular 1.3+, you can also look into using the ng-model-options debounce option.

Answer (score 1):

Use blur instead of key up.
Try following:

```
angular.module('installApp')
.directive('pwCheck', function ($http) {
  return {
   require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      var firstPassword = '#' + attrs.pwCheck;
        elem.on('blur', function () {
          scope.$apply(function () {
                ctrl.$setValidity('pwmatch', elem.val() === $(firstPassword).val());
            });
        });
      }
   }
});
```

**Note**: Removed add method on elem. Will throw error because there no add method defined on element.